# Which dua can I recite at the last sitting of salah?

Tags: salat, hadith, dua

What dua can I read after **attahiyat and durood** and before **Salam**, in the last sitting of Salah?

In hadith I found that Prophet Hazrat Muhammad (PBUH) used to recite a lot of dua, hamd, and sana in the last sitting of salah. I need the duas from **Sahih Hadith**.

Comment: Do you mean before the Salam or after? i guess at least for one of both we have had that question before!

Comment: @MediSaif the dua is for within salah. After Attahiyat, we say durood, as far I know prophet Muhammad (PBUH) used to do some extra hamd and thana before the salam. I want to know the duas from Authentic Hadith.

Answer (score 3):

You can find those dua's in the booklet called hisn al-Muslim ([hisnul muslim](http://www.islamguiden.com/hisnulmuslim/024.htm)) by Sa'id ibn Ali ibn Wahf al-Qahtany سعيد بن علي بن وهف القحطاني Chapter 24 - الدعاء بعد التشهد الأخير وقبل السلام:

- About the same dua' with a slightly difference [#55](http://sunnah.com/muslim/5/162) and [#56](http://sunnah.com/muslim/5/163) both are also in sahih al-Bukhari
  Here's a transliteration of #56:

> Allahumma inni audhu bika min 'adhabi l-qabri wa 'audhu bika min
> fitnatil-masihi d-dajjal, wa 'audhu bika min fitnati l-mahya
> walmamati, Allahumma inni 'audhu bika min al-ma'thami wal-maghram

a transliteration of #55 is [here](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1423)

- [#57](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/227) also in both Sahih books

> Alahumma inni zalamtu nafsi zulman kathiran wa la yaghfiru a-dhunub illa
> anta faghfirli maghfiratan min 'indika warhamni innaka
> anta l-Ghafurur-Rahim

- [#58](http://sunnah.com/muslim/6/240)

> Allahum-maghfir li ma qaddamtu wa ma akh-khartu, wa ma asrartu, wa ma
> a'lantu, wa ma asraftu, wa ma Anta a'lamu bihi minni. Antal-Muqqadimu,
> wa Antal-Mu'akh-khiru. La ilaha illa Anta

- [#59](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/8/107) sahih in Sunan Abi Dawod and also to be find in Sunan an-Nasa'i, some scholars say it should be said after the salam, some say before or after and some tend to before!

> Allahumma a'inni 'ala dhikrika wa shukrika, wa husni 'ibadatika

- [#60](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/80/62) this is also said before and after salam

> Alla-humma inni a'udhu bika minal-jubni wal- bukhl, wa a'udhu bika min
> an uradda ila ardhalil-'umur, wa a'udhu bika min fitnatid-dunya, wa
> a'udhu bika min fitnatil-qabr

- [#61](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/402) it should also be in sunan ibn Majah!

> Allahuma inni as-aluka l-Jannah wa a'udu bika mina n-nar

- [#62](http://sunnah.com/nasai/13/127) also in Musnad al Imam Ahmad

> Allahumma bi 'ilmika l-ghaiba wa qudratika 'alal-khalqi ahini ma 'alimtal-hayata khairan li, wa tawaffani idha 'alimtal-wafata khairan li. Allahumma as'aluka khashyataka fil-ghaibi wash-shahadati wa as'aluka kalimatal haqui fir-rida'i wal ghadab, wa as'aluka l-qasda fil faqr wal-ghina, wa as'aluka na'iman la yanfadu wa as'aluka qurrata 'ainan la tanqati'u wa as'alukar-rida'i ba'dal-qada'i wa as'aluka bardal 'aishi ba'dal-mawti, wa as'aluka ladhata n-nazari ila wajhika wash-shawqa ila liqa'ika fi (*or in an other narration* min) ghayri darraa'in muddirra wa la fitnatin mudillatin, Allahumma zayyina bi zinatil-imani waj'alna hudatan muhtadin

- [#63](http://sunnah.com/nasai/13/123) also in sunan abi Dawod and Musnad Ahmad

> Allahumma inni as'aluka ya Allah! Bi-annaka l-Wahidul-Ahadu-Samad, alladhi lam yalid wa lam yowled, wa lam yakun lahu kufu'an (*or if recited according the language of hafs* kufuwan) ahad, an taghfirali dhunubi, innaka antal-Ghafurur-Rahim

- [#64](http://sunnah.com/nasai/13/122) this dua' was also mentioned in all the Sunan books

> Allahumma inni as'aluka bi-anna lakal-hamd, lailaha illa ant,
> al-mannanu badi'us-samawati wal-ard, ya dhal-jalali wal-ikram! Ya
> hayyu ya qayyum! Inni as'aluka al Jannah wa a'udu bika mina n-nar

- [#65](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/8/78) is a dua' which includes parts of #63 and #64 and is quoted in Musnad Ahmad, sunan ibn Majah and sunan at-Tirmidhi

> Allāhumma inni as'aluka bi annī ashhadu annaka antallah, la ilaha illa ant, al-ahadu-s-Samad, alladhi lam yalid wa lam yulad, wa lam yakun lahu kufuwan ahad

---

Note i have changed the transliteration or added some additions in it when they were different then in my reference or lack some words.

See also this [Fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/104163).

And Allah knows best!