# Dua after namaz or dua in namaz

Tags: salat, dua

My first question was ([Not praying in masjid when imam is a government paid employee?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31060/not-praying-in-masjid-when-imam-is-a-government-paid-employee)). I want to add some more in it. They did not say Dua after salat by raising their hands. I asked them why you are not doing Dua. They said Salat is Dua, Muhammad (Peace Be Upon Him) did not did this kind of act. If you want to make Dua, then you should make Dua when you are in Sajda in prayer or in any state but you should be in prayer. The Dua after salat is not valid, and group Dua is also wrong, according to them. So is it true that Dua after prayer is not valid act?

Comment: The answer of your question -in the whole- is yes and no. Yes you can perform dua' after prayer and there are some known dua's (see here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28781/which-dua-can-i-recite-at-the-last-sitting-of-salah/28800#28800). And no a group dua' is considered as wrong or bida'h by salafi scholars and this view seems to have good evidences!

Comment: but now a days, after every prayers, the imam turn himself towards all the people and say dua. so they are doing bida'h?

Comment: I know there are a lot of dua, but my question is that, raising the hands after dua is also bida'h? or we should make dua in prayer?

Comment: I don't know what you exactly mean: usually one raises his hands while speaking out/reciting the words of the dua'. Dua' is also a part of the prayer but we can perform dua' at any time and any where, as it is what is called dhikr.

Comment: so you are saying that, perform dua at anytime is good. Raising hands and not raising hands, it doesn't matter?

Comment: There are many situations where we perform dua' without raising hands (for example in salat, in sa'y, in jumu'a the imam should never raise his hands for dua' while the congregation can do so if he asks for rain). So dua' doesn't by default mean one should raise his hands. But after a prayer or if you are alone at night and want to ask Allah you are free to raise your hands!

Answer (score 3):

Someone once asked Prophet Muhammad (s) when is the time to make dua:
        
*“the Prophet, salAllahu alayhi wasalam, was asked “which Du’a is more heard (by Allah)?” The Prophet, salAllahu alayhi wasalam, said, “The Du’a during the last part of the night and after the Fard prayers.”*

[at-Tirmidhi, 3421]

Also, Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) used to recite **Qunoot** after second rakah, which is also the dua (supplication).

Once Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) was asked what is the best time to say dua:

*Narrated Sahel Ibn Sa'ad (RA): that the Messenger of Allah (SAW) said: 'Two will not be rejected, Supplication when the Adhan (call of prayer) is being called, and at the time of the rain'. [Al-Hakim 2: 114, and Abu Dawud #2540, ibn Majah]*

Hence it proves that you can make dua at anytime, Almighty is all hearing and listens to our queries everytime.

Comment: exaclty, but they have not describe that make the dua by raising your hands . isn't it?

Comment: @AsadAli I remember, when battle of trench took place, it is written that Prophet (PBUH) raised his hands and asked ALLAH to help Ali (a) win. Other companions there replied "Ameen". which also answers your group dua as well.
You can check that.

Comment: @TahirHussainMir well this isn't what i would call group dua'. I know group dua' where everybody is reciting the same words, not where somebody is reciting while the others say "Ameen"!