# How can a muslim with dead non-muslim parents reconcile "not asking forgiveness for his parents" and dua of 14:41?

Tags: parents, forgiveness

I was taught to recite [14:40-41] in my salah:

> Our Lord, forgive me **and my parents** and the believers the Day the account is established." [14:41]

And the verse 9:113 says I cannot ask forgiveness for non-believers after they have passed away.

> It is not for the Prophet and those who have believed to ask forgiveness for the polytheists, even if they were relatives, after it has become clear to them that they are companions of Hellfire.[9:113]

How can a person with non-muslim parents recite 14:41 in his salah or in general when it contradicts ayah 9:113 (the rule that he cannot ask forgiveness for dead non-muslims)?

Comment: @UmH 14:41 is a dua for forgiveness of parents whereas 9:113 is a prohibition asking forgiveness for this muslim person whose parents are non-muslims. They are contradicting for this muslim if he includes 14:41 in his regular list of duas outside the salah. i am questioning how to reconcile this contradiction?

Comment: this part of surah Ibrahim starts with "and when Abraham said ".."..." (14.35) and the quoted words of Ibrahim as continue until 14.42,  so when you recite it you are reciting what Allah is quoting from Ibrahim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reconciliation is needed when there are two conflicting **commands**. The dua in salah is not obligatory, nor is it prescribed with only these words rather one is free to make any dua, some of the prescribed ones are listed [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28781).

A person with non-muslim parents can make some other dua. Or they can make this dua but intend by ولوالدي not their immediate parents but some Muslim (grand) parents such as Adam and Eve, Noah etc.

**Ref:**

> إذا قال: اللهم اغفر لي ولوالدي وكان أبواه قد ماتا كافرين انصرفت المغفرة إلى آدم وحواء لأنهما والدا الخلق أجمع
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://shamela.ws/book/20855/3706#p1)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

How can a Muslim not reconcile with dead non-Muslim parents by "asking forgiveness for their parents" and praying 14:41?
Ayatollah Mojtaba Tehrani, referring to the verses of the Qur'an about praying for infidels and polytheists, said: God says to the Prophet: If you ask for forgiveness for these or do not ask for forgiveness, it is equal for them. Even if you ask forgiveness for them seventy times, it is of no use. These will not be forgiven, because they disbelieved in God and His Messenger, and God does not guide the wicked people.

https://www.mehrnews.com/news/1659840/